# How can I score edge amount/length?

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

Given the following two pictures, how could I score the "amount" or length" of an edge in a picture?

Picture A

[image]

Picture B

[image]

I would like to find and algorithm which would give me a score between 0 and 1, depending on the length or "amount" of an edge in a picture compared to picture width/height (depending on the orientation, for horizontal edges it would be width and vice versa). Runnin the algorithm on the picture A would return something close to 1, and on the picture B around 0.5. I'm using OpenCV and coding in C++.

Comment: 1) find contours of paper 2) get bounding rectangle of contour 3) compute ratio of rectangle width to image width and rectangle height to image height

Comment: Why don't you count the pixels ?

Comment: Note that your relative score is not correctly defined. Because curves can have no preferred orientation (think of a circle), and can be much longer than the image side (think of a spiral).